# LESS CSS compilation error on subtracting color values

Tags: colors, compilation, less, subtraction

I'm running lessc my.less my.css.

Code:

```
@background: #343434;

input[type='text'] { 
    border: 1px solid (@background-#222);
}
```

Fails providing this error

> NameError: variable @background- is undefined in ...

However,

```
input[type='text'] { 
    border: 1px solid (@background+#222);
}
```

Will work.

I have read about BOM, this is not the case. I have also checked that my less compiler is installed with latest nodejs. I also tried #222222. Out of ideas.

Comment: it's weird that '-' doesn't work, but I found the difference() function which works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` may be part of an identifier. This is why it tells you it can't find the variable `@background-`. On the other hand the `+` is never part of an identifier and so less knows that the variable is `@background`. You just have to insert a space to get it working:

```
input[type='text'] { 
    border: 1px solid (@background -#222);
}
```